# Match Lines of Rectangles

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to find rectangles in an image in Matlab. I use `houghlines` function to find lines. It finds lines with points but not in order. Is there any way to find match same rectangle's lines? Some  points are close but some points have distance to other line's points.

this code from matlab's houghlines's example:

```
I  = imread('e1.jpg');
I =rgb2gray(I);
rotI = imrotate(I,360,'crop');
BW = edge(rotI,'canny');
[H,T,R] = hough(BW);
imshow(H,[],'XData',T,'YData',R,...
            'InitialMagnification','fit');
xlabel('\theta'), ylabel('\rho');
axis on, axis normal, hold on;
P  = houghpeaks(H,20,'threshold',ceil(0.3*max(H(:))));
x = T(P(:,2)); y = R(P(:,1));
plot(x,y,'s','color','white');
% Find lines and plot them
lines = houghlines(BW,T,R,P,'FillGap',5,'MinLength',7);
figure, imshow(rotI), hold on
max_len = 0;
for k = 1:length(lines)
   xy = [lines(k).point1; lines(k).point2];
   plot(xy(:,1),xy(:,2),'LineWidth',2,'Color','green');

   % Plot beginnings and ends of lines
   plot(xy(1,1),xy(1,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','yellow');
   plot(xy(2,1),xy(2,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','red');

   % Determine the endpoints of the longest line segment
   len = norm(lines(k).point1 - lines(k).point2);
   if ( len > max_len)
      max_len = len;
      xy_long = xy;
   end
end

% highlight the longest line segment
plot(xy_long(:,1),xy_long(:,2),'LineWidth',2,'Color','blue');
```

I can't add image because of reputation but it has 3 black rectangles in white backroung

Comment: please upload your raw image and code

Comment: Can you upload some example images and some result images?